# How can I unfold the recurrence: T(n)=2T((n+2)/3)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, unfold

I'm trying to solve this recurrence, but I don't know how to unfold it.

```
T(n)=2T((n+2)/3) + 1
```

Can I ignore that "+2" and solve it as it was 2T(n/3) + 1?

This comes from  a from a problem that uses a `V[a..b]` array and makes this return:

```
return V(X) + f(V, a, Y) + f(V, Z, b)
```

Where `Y` is `(2a+b)/3 and Z is (a+2b)/3`

So: `((b-a+3)/3) = ((n+2)/3)`

Comment: Is this a programming question? Or simply a mathematics question? If it is the latter, please check out the [Math Stack Exchange site](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Sort of. The rigorous version of this trick is to set `U(n) = T(n+1)` and write

```
U(n) = T(n+1)
     = 2T((n+1+2)/3) + 1
     = 2T(n/3 + 1) + 1
     = 2U(n/3) + 1.
```

Then solve for `U` (e.g., `U(n) = O(n^log3(2))`) and then you should be able to find an asymptotic expression for `T` of the same order.